# Module not found: Can't resolve 'react' in '/node_modules/@restart/hooks/esm'

Tags: node.js

I'm having trouble running my app. I get the following error. Can someone please help?

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react' in '/node_modules/@restart/hooks/esm'
```